# How to register event listener for components in the bean in JSF?

Tags: jsf, listener

Is there any way to register event listeners for components at a central point like the bean?

Is something like this possible?

```
@PostConstruct
public void setup() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIViewRoot view = facesContext.getViewRoot();
    view.getComponentByName("toolBar:save").addActionListener(com.sample.SaveListener);
    view.getComponentByName("form:save").addActionListener(com.sample.SaveListener);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all components are necessarily available during bean's (post)construction. The bean will be constructed whenever EL needs to resolve `#{bean}` for the first time, which may be too early. Do it during the pre render view event instead.

Add the following tag to your view:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.setup}" />
```

Then you can do the necessary job in that method:

```
public void setup() {
    UIViewRoot view = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    ((UICommand) view.findComponent("toolBar:save")).addActionListener(new com.sample.SaveListener());
    ((UICommand) view.findComponent("form:save")).addActionListener(new com.sample.SaveListener());
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks alot! You just made my day :) Is there a way to add non-action listeners to components in this way too?

Comment: You could also use `Application#subscribeToEvent()` with a `SystemEventListener` or `ComponentSystemEventListener` implementation.

Comment: Thanks again, I will take a closer look on these 2 :)

Comment: I don't have sufficiant reputation to comment your answer ... :\ @BalusC: shouldn't it be view.findComponent(...)
instead of view.getFindComponent(...) Or has the method signature changed since 2012 ...